# while loop variable update

Tags: c, while-loop, infinite-loop

Please look at this code:

```
int page;
int stop = FALSE;

while (!stop) {
    printf("stop0  %i\n", stop);

    if (physmem[fifo_index % opts.phys_pages] == NULL) {
        stop = TRUE;
        page = fifo_index % opts.phys_pages;
        printf("stop1 %i\n", stop);

    } else if (physmem[fifo_index % opts.phys_pages]->gc_bit == 0) {
        physmem[fifo_index % opts.phys_pages]->gc_bit = 1;
        printf("stop2 %i\n", stop);

    } else if (physmem[fifo_index % opts.phys_pages]->gc_bit == 1) {
        stop = TRUE;
        page = fifo_index % opts.phys_pages;
        printf("stop3 %i\n", stop);

    }
    printf("sto4 %i\n", stop);

    fifo_index++;
    printf("stop5 %i\n", stop);

}
```

The output is:

```
stop0  0
stop1 1
stop4 1
stop5 1
stop0  0 '<<< I dont understand this part'
stop1 1
stop4 1
stop5 1
          '<<<< The code exits here!! In the second loop...whyy??'
```

Comment: Is this code located in some outer loop?

Comment: I noticed you didn't actually copy/paste the output because "sto4" is misspelled in your code but not in your output.

Comment: How do you know it looped twice?  Is it possible you called this function twice?

Comment: @Adam @mu, you are correct, I corrected the spelling while posting it here. good catch! its been about 20 hours i have been here so - yes all - sorry for the frantic post - the function housing this loop was being called over and over again for each logical reference ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a `printf` above `while` statement and check if you are entering the loop twice.

Comment: i feel pretty stoopid. tired :(